# How to read foreign key constraint to a variable, drop the constraint, alter few columns, recreate the constraint with same name of a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL, i need to read the foreign key constraint name to a variable, alter few columns length and then recreate the same foreign key constraint on the table.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `l_report_ratings` (
  `rating_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_header_id` varchar(700) NOT NULL,
  `source_system_id` int NOT NULL,
  `rated_by_userid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rating` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `rating_update_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(750) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_report_header_source_system_userid` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`,`rated_by_userid`),
  KEY `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

In the above table i want to decrease the size of `report_header_id` to varchar(500) and increase the size of `rated_by_userid' to varchar (256). I able to this with alter statements individually like this

```
ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id`;
ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings MODIFY COLUMN report_header_id varchar(500) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings MODIFY COLUMN rated_by_userid varchar(256) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`);
```

But i want this to be done dynamically in this way

- Read the foreign key constraint name to variable.
- Drop the foreign key constraint.
- Decrease the column size of `report_header_id`.
- Increase the column size of `rated_by_userid'.
- And then add back the foreign key constraint with same name read into
  the variable.

I could achieve this for one of the table in SQL Server. The code is as below

```
DECLARE @constraint_name VARCHAR(500);
SELECT @constraint_name = name  
FROM sys.objects  
WHERE type = 'PK' AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = N'l_user_preferences';
PRINT 'Constraint Name is : ' + @constraint_name;
-- Delete the primary key constraint.  
EXEC('ALTER TABLE l_user_preferences DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @constraint_name);
PRINT 'Constraint Name : ' + @constraint_name +' Dropped ';
-- updating the column UserId length
EXEC('alter table l_user_preferences alter column UserId varchar(256) NOT NULL');
PRINT 'Column length updated';
-- Add the constraint with the same name
EXEC('ALTER TABLE l_user_preferences ADD CONSTRAINT ' +  @constraint_name + ' PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])');
PRINT 'Constraint Name : ' + @constraint_name +' Restored ';
GO
```

- Declared a variable.
- Read the primary key constraint name to the variable.
- Using alter command drop the primary key constraint.
- Using alter command alter the size of UserId column.
- And recreated the primary key constraint using the variable name
  which has the primary key constraint name.

Is there a similar way in MYSQL that i can dynamically read the constraint name, store it in a variable, alter the columns and recreate the constraint with the same name stored in the variable.

I could read the constraint name from MYSQL using the following query

```
  SELECT constraint_name FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
         WHERE table_schema = 'schema' AND table_name='table_name' and constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY';
```

Any help/suggestions. Can it be achieved through procedures in MYSQL ?.

Answer (score 0):

You actaully dpon't need the foreign name for tht, you can disable the foreigns keys

```
CREATE TABLE l_report_header_data(`REPORT_HEADER_ID` varchar(700), `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID` int, PRIMARY KEY (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`))
```

```
INSERT INTO l_report_header_data VALUES ('123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890',1)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `l_report_ratings` (
  `rating_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_header_id` varchar(700) NOT NULL,
  `source_system_id` int NOT NULL,
  `rated_by_userid` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rating` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `rating_update_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(750) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_report_header_source_system_userid` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`,`rated_by_userid`),
  KEY `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
INSERT INTO l_report_ratings (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`,`rated_by_userid`,`rating`,`rating_update_timestamp`,`comment`)
VALUEs ('123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'
  ,1,'testuser',1, NOW(),'testcomment')
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `changecolumns`()
    NO SQL
BEGIN 

   -- Get foreign key name
    SELECT constraint_name INTO @fk_nmae FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
         WHERE table_name='l_report_ratings' and constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY';
    -- Disable all foreign keys
    SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
      -- Run dynamic comands
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
     'ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings MODIFY COLUMN report_header_id varchar(500) NOT NULL;';
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM 
        'ALTER TABLE l_report_ratings MODIFY COLUMN rated_by_userid varchar(256) NOT NULL;';
      EXECUTE stmt1;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
     -- Enable teh foreign keys
    SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
END;
```

```
call changecolumns()
```

```
show CREATE  TABLE l_report_ratings
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| l_report_ratings | CREATE TABLE `l_report_ratings` ( `rating_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `report_header_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `source_system_id` int NOT NULL, `rated_by_userid` varchar(256) NOT NULL, `rating` tinyint NOT NULL, `rating_update_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL, `comment` varchar(750) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`), UNIQUE KEY `unique_report_header_source_system_userid` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`,`rated_by_userid`), KEY `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`), CONSTRAINT `fk_l_report_rating_report_header_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NKVTn-60)

Comment: Executing the above stored procedure in MYSQL workbench gives an error
11:20:44 call changecolumns() Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes 0.000 sec

Comment: you need to check if all rows fit into your new schema, so you should check the length